# Bootstrap 3.0 datepicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm trying to include a datetime picker on my bootstrap page.

I dont know what im doing wrong. The button just doesn't do anything!

I included the js from bootstrap and bootstrap-datepicker and moment.js just like eonasdan says...

Could anyone help?

```
<html class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

    <title>Test</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
    <style type="text/css">
body {
                padding-top: 50px;
                padding-bottom: 20px;
            }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/datepicker3.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/carousel.css" type="text/css">

    <script src="../js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
   <!--
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script> -->
    <script src="../js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
    <script src="../js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
    <script src="../js/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
    <script src="../js/bootstrap-datepicker.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

And in body...

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker'>
        <input type='text' class="form-control" data-format="DD/MM/YYYY" />
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($){
        $("#datetimepicker").datetimepicker({
            pickTime: false
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: 1.11 just came out...

Comment: 1.11 its really new, and has support for ie 6,7,8. 2.X has the same features than 1.11, but no support for old browsers @Adosi

Answer (score 1):

There looks to be multiple Bootstrap date-pickers, but for the vast majority of them you should be using `$("#datetimepicker").datepicker();` rather than `$("#datetimepicker").datetimepicker();`

Are you looking for a date-picker or a date-time-picker?

Comment: Im looking for datepicker. Tried already $("#datetimepicker").datepicker(); but didnt workd

Comment: That's because you are selecting your div.  You should be selecting the textbox.  I suggest adding the class 'date-picker' to your textbox and then using `$('.date-picker').datepicker();` to load the date picker on it.  Or you can move the `id='datepicker'` down to your textbox and leave everything else as is.  I usually find it better to use a class so that when you need to add another, just give the next textbox that class and it will work automatically.